# How to allocate GPUs on AWS Free Tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, keras

**strong text**Is it possible to get GPUs allocated on AWS free tier? If so can someone explain the steps? I tried on Amazon EC2 but could not get GPUs allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) includes the following for Amazon EC2:

- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES **t2.micro or t3.micro** instance dependent on region
- 750 hours per month of Windows **t2.micro or t3.micro** instance dependent on region

The `micro` instances do not support GPUs. Thus, you cannot stay within the Free Tier while using GPUs.